# Custom view inside scroll view inside table cell is not responding to events

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a UITableView in my view controller, and inside the cell there's a horizontal UIScrollView and inside this scroll view, I created many instances of a custom UIView (loaded from NIB file)

```
UITableViewCell
-- UIScrollView
   -- MyView: UIView
```

Now MyView is not detecting touches, userInteractionEnabled is set to YES on every view in the hierarchy and I tried both ways

1. Implement touchesEnded: in MyView
2. Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to it

Both ways don't work, I guess it's something related to the fact that I have a UIScrollView inside the UITableViewCell

I am writing the application in Swift, not Objective-C, I don't think it matters since I guess it's a UIKit issue but who knows.

If you have any hint, I am all ears.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for this case is add **UITableViewCustomCell** and add **UICollectionView** with horizontal scroll in Custom cell . It is more optimized way than adding UIView in scroll view because you can greatly speed things up. Instead of instantiating a lot of cells, you just instantiate as many as needed, i.e. as many that are visible (this is handled automatically). If scrolling to an area in the list where there are "cells" that haven't got their visual representation yet, instead of instantiating new ones, you reuse already existing ones.

Comment: I have a custom view cell and I totally agree with you that the best solution that is provided by the UIKit is the UICollectionView but the app is already built and I don't want to make major changes to the hierarchy.